# How to compare a couple binary bytes in code?

Tags: perl

I read a binary file and want to make sure that some specific bytes have some specific value. What's the most perl way of doing this?

```
my $blob = File::Slurp::read_file( 'blob.bin', {binmode=>'raw'} );
substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) == #equals what?
```

I want to test if bytes 5-8 equal `0x32 0x32 0x00 0x04`. What should I compare the substr to?

Comment: fyi, [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) has a saner interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl
substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) eq "\x32\x32\x00\x04"
```

If it's a 32-bit unsigned number, you might prefer the following:

```perl
unpack( "L>", substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) ) == 0x32320004   # Big endian
unpack( "L<", substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) ) == 0x04003232   # Little endian
unpack( "L",  substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) ) == ...          # Native endian

unpack( "N",  substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) ) == 0x32320004   # Big endian
unpack( "V",  substr( $blob, 4, 4 ) ) == 0x04003232   # Little endian
```

(Use `l` instead oaf `L` for signed 32-bit ints.)

`substr` can even be avoided when using `unpack`.

```perl
unpack( "x4 N", $blob ) == 0x32320004
```

You could also use a regex match.

```perl
$blob =~ /^.{4}\x32\x32\x00\x04/s

$blob =~ /^ .{4} \x32\x32\x00\x04 /sx

my $packed = pack( "N", 0x32320004 );
$blob =~ /^ .{4} \Q$packed\E /sx
```

Comment: Thank you, the regex works fine! I guess the `/s` is to handle newline bytes? The first example however, I get this error: `Argument "22\0^D" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`

Comment: Yeah, `/s` allows `.` to handle byte `0A` in the first four bytes. // Oops, I copied your incorrect `==` without thinking. It should be `eq`.